# Set buffer timeout in Flink from a config file

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

How can I pass ['execution.buffer-timeout'](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/deployment/config.html#execution-buffer-timeout) configuration in Flink? I have tried adding this config in `flink-conf.yaml` but it did not work. Where do we need to set this configuration?

I have tried setting it programmatically with below code but somehow it's not reducing the latency for me. I just wanted to know if I can set this via a config file

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createRemoteEnvironment(hots, port, null));
env.setBufferTimeout(2);
StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env, streamSettings);
tableEnv.executeSql(query);
```

Not sure if I'm missing something here.

**Update**

To test out if the property is being passed to Flink, I have tried setting `BufferTimeout` property to -2 in `flink-conf.yaml`, but it did not throw any exception. I have got exception when I set it to -2 in the code. This made me feel that the property is not being passed to Flink. Also my latency numbers have a definite pattern ranging from 45ms to 100ms continuously. This indicated that there is some buffering happening in Flink before it is delivered.

Can you point me to the file where we are setting this in Flink github repo?

Answer (score 0):

`env.setBufferTimeout(2)` in your code, or setting `execution.buffer-timeout: 2` in flink-conf.yaml (or on the command line via `-Dexecution.buffer-timeout=2`) should work.

Note that this won't have any noticeable effect if your buffers aren't timing out. Perhaps your buffers are usually full? You can compute the average buffer size from the metrics (`numBytesInRemote / numBuffersInRemote`) and compare that to the buffer size (32 KiB) to estimate how often buffers are timing out.

Note that flink-conf.yaml is not read if you are running Flink as a mini-cluster (in other words, running the client application and the job manager and task manager all in one JVM, as one does in the IDE, for example).

Comment: I have updated my answer now with additional details. Looks like there is some buffering taking place from Flink side in my case.

Comment: I've expanded my answer a bit.